# Why the best loss doesn't updated?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost, hyperopt

I'm attempting to run parameter optimization using HYPEROPT, but I'm not seeing any changes in the printing of the best loss value.

I attempted to change the accuracy sign, but it did not help. I tried testing models in my own randomized trials, and the results were much better. How could I optimize the parameters?

I followed [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/prashant111/a-guide-on-xgboost-hyperparameters-tuning).

Minimal code example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from hyperopt import STATUS_OK, Trials, fmin, hp, tpe
import xgboost as xgb

def objective(space):
    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(
        n_estimators=space['n_estimators'], max_depth=int(space['max_depth']), gamma=space['gamma'],
        reg_alpha=int(space['reg_alpha']), min_child_weight=int(space['min_child_weight']),
        colsample_bytree=int(space['colsample_bytree']))

    evaluation = [(train, train_labels), (test, test_labels)]

    clf.fit(train, train_labels,
            eval_set=evaluation, eval_metric="auc",
            early_stopping_rounds=10, verbose=True)

    pred = clf.predict(test)
    accuracy = roc_auc_score(test_labels, pred)
    print("ROC:", accuracy)
    return {'loss': -accuracy, 'status': STATUS_OK}

space = {'max_depth': hp.quniform("max_depth", 3, 300, 1),
         'gamma': hp.uniform('gamma', 1, 9),
         'reg_alpha': hp.quniform('reg_alpha', 5, 180, 1),
         'reg_lambda': hp.uniform('reg_lambda', 0, 1),
         'colsample_bytree': hp.uniform('colsample_bytree', 0.1, 1),
         'min_child_weight': hp.quniform('min_child_weight', 0, 10, 1),
         'n_estimators': 300,
         'seed': 0
         }

train, train_labels, train_Ids = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test, test_labels, test_Ids = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

trials = Trials()

best_hyperparams = fmin(fn=objective,
                        space=space,
                        algo=tpe.suggest,
                        max_evals=400,
                        trials=trials)

print("The best hyperparameters are : ", "\n")
print(best_hyperparams)
```

The result, which is repeated at the start of each iteration, is for example:

```
2%|▏         | 9/400 [00:07<05:31,  1.18trial/s, best loss: -0.5]
...
5%|▍         | 19/400 [00:17<05:58,  1.06trial/s, best loss: -0.5]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot recreate your exact issue without your dataset, but I tried it with the `sklearn` dataset `load_breast_cancer`.  I quickly get scores better than 0.5, but there *are* many scores with that baseline score.  I think it's because your `reg_alpha` range is too high, so that some of the models end up pruned to nothing.  Hopefully after your optimization samples some smaller alphas, the `tpe` algorithm will start to focus on more useful values.

You might check:

```py
import numpy as np
alphas = [(trial['misc']['vals']['reg_alpha'][0], trial['result']['loss']) for trial in trials.trials]
print(np.array([alpha for alpha, score in alphas if score == -0.5]).min())
print(np.array([alpha for alpha, score in alphas if score != -0.5]).max())
```

which for me gives `85.0` and `89.0`; there's a little overlap, but broadly speaking, alphas greater than 85 kill the model.